# Editing data.tar.gz inside of .ipk file

Tags: linux, tar, ipkg

Is there a simple way to edit the contents of the `data.tar.gz` archive inside of an `.ipk` file??

Comment: Can you just use ipkg-extract-file to extract the file you need to edit?

Comment: I need to edit the `data.tar.gz` and add a `symlink`, then install the package. I can extract the file, edit it, i can put it back in the `data.tar.gz`, but I can't remake the `.ipk` file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So figured out how to do this, in case anyone is wondering:

**Step 1:** Extract the `.ipk` archive using `ar x <archive name>`

This should create a `control.tar.gz`, a `data.tar.gz`, and a `debian-binary`

**Step 2:** Then extract the `data.tar.gz` using `tar -xvzf data.tar.gz`

**Step 3:** Modify the extracted file(s) as necessary

**Step 4:** Then re-create `data.tar.gz` using the modified files by using `tar -czvf data.tar.gz <list of files or folders separated by spaces>`

**Step 5:** Overwrite the `data.tar.gz` in the original `.ipk` archive using `ar r <archive name> data.tar.gz` to complete the process